# React routes working locally but not through Heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku, routes

I’ve built an app with Express and React which has GET and POST routes which work perfectly locally. I’ve deployed through Heroku and nothing is working anymore! I’m just getting a 404 error. I’ve tried to create a static.json file which hasn’t worked, although I didn't use Create-React-App to set it up anyway.

This is my index.js:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const app = express()

const router = require('./config/router')
const { port, dbURI } = require('./config/environment')
const errorHandler = require('./lib/errorHandler')
const logger = require('./lib/logger')

app.use(express.static(`${__dirname}/public`))

app.use(express.static(`${__dirname}/dist`))

mongoose.connect(dbURI, { useNewURLParser: true, useCreateIndex: true})

app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.use(logger)

app.use('/api', router)

app.use(errorHandler)

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Up and running on port ${port}`))

module.exports = app
```

router.js

```
const vacancies = require('../controllers/vacancies')

router.route('/vacancies')
  .get(vacancies.index)
  .post(vacancies.create)

router.route('/vacancies/:id')
  .get(vacancies.show)

module.exports = router
```

controller:

```
//tested in insomnia - works
function indexRoute(req, res, next) {
  Vacancy
    .find(req.query)
    .then(vacancies => res.status(200).json(vacancies))
    .catch(next)
}

//tested in insomnia - works
function showRoute(req, res, next) {
  Vacancy
    .findById(req.params.id)
    .then(vacancy => res.status(200).json(vacancy))
    .catch(next)
}

//tested in insomnia - works
function createRoute(req, res) {
  Vacancy
    .create(req.body)
    .then(vacancy => res.status(201).json(vacancy))
    .catch(err => res.status(422).json(err))
}

module.exports = {
  index: indexRoute,
  show: showRoute,
  create: createRoute
}
```

and lastly, environment file:

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 4000
const dbURI = process.env.MONGODB_URI || `mongodb://localhost/dxw-job-board-${process.env.NODE_ENV || 'dev'}`

module.exports = { port, dbURI }
```

This is for a code test for a job I really want to super anxious about it not working properly - any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Thank you for your help!! It turns out it had less to do with my code and more with me not having created a mongo db as an addon in heroku...

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this and pulled my hair out when I first tried to deploy an app on Heroku (was my first experience with any sort of deployment actually). On the production server (Heroku) you should be serving the static files from the `build` directory, not the `/public` directory.

Something like this:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  // react build directory /public 
} else {
  // Local production env react /public dir
}
```

This should tell Node that it's on Heroku (or whatever platform you use) and needs to use the production build and not the development version.

Hope that solves the issue for you.